# Помогите написать java код, работающий с php и обрабатывающий json

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Привет! Имеется таблица с пятью столбцами (MYSQL) и имеется php скрипт, который через json возвращает значения в массиве, взятые из таблицы.
Значения в правильном порядке такие: adress, name, age, alcohol, closed. Все string если что (вдруг нужно..).
Задача такая: написать код (java), который получит все данные и заполнит ListView в активити. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, где запускается php-скрипт. Это удаленный сервер или все происходит локально? Через веб-сервер или "php foo.php"?

Comment: Да, простите. Скрипт находится на сервере, есть прямая ссылка на него.

Answer (score 2):

Почему именно 'ListView', а не RecyclerView?
Но не суть. В последнее время, для подобных задач пользуюсь библиотеками от square (http://square.github.io/)
Для данной - Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Что-то, примерно, так:

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}

public void getDataFromServer() {
    Retrofit retrofit = (new Retrofit.Builder())
            .baseUrl(URL_SERVER)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService .class);

    Call<List<Repo>> call = service.listRepos("user");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Repo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Repo>> call, Response<List<Repo>> response) {
            for (Repo repo:
                    response.body()) {
                    adapter.add(repo);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Repo>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
  }
```

**UPD:**
Repo - это класс, по стуктуре соответствующий получаемому элементу JSON.
Те. если возвращается такой массив

```
[
{
    "adress":"address1", 
    "name": "name1",
    "age":,18,
    "alcohol": false,
    "closed": true
},
{
    "adress":"address1", 
    "name": "name1",
    "age":,12,
    "alcohol": false,
    "closed": true
},
{
    "adress":"address1", 
    "name": "name1",
    "age":,19,
    "alcohol": true,
    "closed": true
}
]
```

Repo будет:

```
class Repo {
    String address;
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean alcohol;
    boolean closed;
}
```

**UPD2** Имена в `Repo` должны или полностью соответствовать полю в json, или можно явно указать соответствие:

```
  @SerializedName("age")
  private int ageInYears;
```

ps. код писал тут, не компилировал.

Comment: Мало что понял из вашего кода.. AS кучу ошибок выдаёт, не могли бы вы написать абсолютно полный код для поставленной задачи?

Comment: по этой ссылке подробные manual об использовании http://square.github.io/retrofit/  стоит внимательно изучить.

Comment: А что такое "Repo" в вашем коде?
Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);

Comment: тут ответить не получилось, дополнил ответ.

Comment: еще раз дополнил.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Единственное что осталось это:
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
Ругается, что не может быть выполнено в Builder'e... Не знаешь в чем проблема?

Comment: полностью код ошибки

Comment: Всё получилось?